# gcloud stop exception - regex / Values must match the following regular expression

Tags: regex, gcloud

I tried to use `gcloud compute instances stop` in order to stop one or more machines. I use the following command:

```
sudo gcloud compute instances stop machine1,machine2 --zone=europe-west1-b
```

So it sends the list as I understand I should do following the docs. It gives me the following exception:

```
Invalid value '[machine1,machine2]'. Values must match the following regular expression: '[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?
```

How should I send it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `gcloud`, this is supposed to be a regex parameter (from what it seems)

```
machine1,machine2
```

From the error,

```
[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?
```

its evident that the regex parameter should not contain anything other than **alphanumerics** and **-**. The parameter `machine1,machine2` contains a `,` that's why you are getting the error.

Try giving space in machine names `machine1 machine2`

**P.S**: I don't have any clue about gcloud.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Try `sudo gcloud compute instances stop machine1 machine2`